# Sphinxsearch _maxmatches

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I`m using SetLimits $max_matches=50000

I need it to display the sql items faster, without search filter.

Everything works fine on my local machine.

The problem apears on the production machine when I set _maxmatches more than 10000.

Thanks

Comment: What is your 'problem'? - you forgot to mention that in your question!

Comment: Sorry if I wasn`t very explicit. So, on the local machine (Windows 7 / Xampp) everything works fine (Including the third SetLimits parameter - $max_matches=50000) but on the production machine if I set _maxmatches more than 10000 I get no results.

Comment: No results at all? Are you changing the 'offset' param too, ie setting it higher than 10,000? Or is just changing max_matches enough to cause an issue? 

Also what is max_matches set to in sphinx.conf?

Comment: Are you perhaps getting an error from sphinx? @barryhunter is correct. The sphinx conf parameter for max_matches is smaller than 10000.

Comment: sphinx.conf -  max_matches = 60000; sphinxapi - $this->_maxmatches = 50000; $cl->SetLimits( 1, 20, 50000 ); I mention that the problem is on the production machine. On my computer is fine. Could be some restrictions from the server?

Comment: I deleted searchd.pid, I rebuilded the index and seems to be ok now.